# Не отображаются значения одной колонки в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема с отображением значения одной колонки в DataGrid.

В БД есть две таблицы: Книга и Жанр (отношение между ними один-ко-многим). Есть DataGrid для книг, вот XAML разметка:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BookDataGrid" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Название" MinWidth="114"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Genre.Name}" Header="Жанр" MinWidth="114"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Author}" Header="Автор" MinWidth="114"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Year}" Header="Год издания" MinWidth="114"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на колонку Жанр, я через Binding прописываю полный путь к названию жанра, а именно: в классе Book есть свойство Genre и через него я указываю свойство Name класса Genre.

```
// Это свойство класса Book
public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
```

При запуске программы в конструкторе MainWindow я в DataGrid загружаю все записи из БД:

```
BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Books.ToList();
```

Здесь у меня нет никаких проблем с отображением корректных значений названия жанра. Как только я хочу добавить новую книгу (создать запись в БД), то у добавленного значения в DataGrid пропадает название жанра, хотя жанр я указываю. В БД Id записей при отношении одни-ко-многим корректно заполняется. Если программу заново перезапустить, то проблема исчезает.

Внизу приведу две функции, из-за которых у меня возникла данная проблема.

```
// Поиск всех книг из БД по выбранному каталогу в таблице CatalogDataGrid
private void CatalogDataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
    {
        Catalog catalog = dbContainer.Catalogs.Find(((Catalog)CatalogDataGrid.SelectedItem).Id);
        UpdateReaderButton.IsEnabled = catalog != null;

        IQueryable<Book> result = dbContainer.Books.Where(c => c.Catalog.Id == catalog.Id);
        BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
    }
}


// Кусок кода одной из функций. Здесь я создаю новую книгу.
using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
{
    Catalog catalog = dbContainer.Catalogs.Find(((Catalog)BookCatalogComboBox.SelectedItem).Id);
    Genre genre = dbContainer.Genres.Find(((Genre)BookGenreComboBox.SelectedItem).Id);
    Book book = new Book
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = BookAuthorTextBox.Text,
        Author = BookAuthorTextBox.Text,
        Year = Convert.ToInt16(BookYearMaskedTextBox.Text),
        Genre = genre,
        Catalog = catalog
    };

    dbContainer.Books.Add(book);
    dbContainer.SaveChanges();
    _window.BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Books.ToList();
}
```

Ещё надо сказать (сейчас кое-что проверил), что вот есть уже добавленные книги в БД. Например, есть книга с жанром "Политика". Если же я захочу добавить другую книгу, но с таким же жанром "Политика", то результат будет таким:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `dbContainer.Books.Include(x=>x.Genre).ToList()`

Comment: Удивительно, но заработало. Благодарю за подсказку. Никогда бы не подумал о том, что для того, чтобы в DataGrid корректно загрузить названия жанров для книг, нужно через Include обращаться к классу Genre для загрузки всех книг и связанные с ними жанры.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад, что помогло